# Solve for $p^a + 1 = 2\cdot q^b$ where $p,q$ are odd primes and $a,b \ge 2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, congruences

Now, clearly, $7^2 + 1 = 2\cdot5^2$.

Is this the only solution? How would I prove this? Or if it is not the only solution, what would be the method to find other solutions?

I'm not clear on how to make progress on this question.

Thanks,

-Larry

Comment: Have you tried using modulo $(2q^b)$? Not sure it's a good idea though.

Comment: Thanks very much for the suggestion.  How would that work?  I'm not clear what using modulo $2q^b$ would accomplish?  What would be the next step if I tried that?

Comment: for $a$ and $b$ both $2$ have a look at Pell's negative equation : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation#The_negative_Pell_equation

Comment: I can't make my suggestion work. I don't think it will work. You could also check with Euler's theorem as the writing looks similar.

Comment: Thanks.  I was not familiar with Pell's negative equation.  I've been working with Euler's Theorem but can't see how it would help in this case.

Comment: **Hint:** Except for $3$, all other odd primes are of the form $6n\pm1$. Likewise, the two exponents *a* and *b* can each be either even or odd. Soon enough, all $2^2{3\choose2}=24$ possible combinations of the four variables $a,b,p,q$ will be reduced to only a few cases.

Comment: I'm not sure if it helps much, but from Zsigmondy's theorem it follows that $a$ can only be a prime or a power of $2$.

Comment: Thanks for the mention of [Zsigmondy's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zsigmondy's_theorem).  I had not heard about it before.

Comment: Thanks, @Lucian.  That is the logic I was looking for.  I had a feeling that I was missing something fundamental.

Comment: I was just wondering, have you eventually managed to solve this using Lucian's hint?

Comment: @barto, not yet.  I am still working on it.  I can see how to group the equation into a smaller possible combinations of variables $a,b,p,q$ but I have not been able to solve yet for any of the combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is at least two more solutions (found by brute force):
$$\begin{align}
41^2+1&=2\cdot29^2\\
239^2+1&=2\cdot13^4
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thanks!  I am starting to think that brute force is the only way forward on this type of problem.